# Problem with supported device orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

this is my first app with xcode. I use xcode 4 . And my first problem is that i maked this 
http://tinypic.com/r/2hykvbt/7
but my app still work only with Portrait orientation . Help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override [`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) in your custom view controller subclass to support all orientations. A simple `return YES;` would suffice. What you are doing right now is setting the [`UISupportedInterfaceOrientations`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10) key in Info.plist. This info helps iOS identify choose the suitable launch orientation for your app based on the current orientation of the device.

Comment: thank you but still don't work :( my application is tab bar based . I tried to put - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
   // return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    return YES;
} in the first view , second vien and the applicationappdelagate , but nothing change . Help please

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TabBarControllers/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH102-SW26). How many tabs are there and have you enabled rotation for all the root view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

It appears in your screenshot that all device orientations are disabled, rather than enabled; clicking the orientations you want once more should help you.

Comment: @user761812 , i'm sorry i posted the wrong picture, i tried with this too and it dont work .http://tinypic.com/r/2njkhup/7 . Maybe i should shange somethink in the info.plist ? but i don't find what :/